BPSK demodulation in microcontroller
I came across this example of how to decode a BPSK stream using a microcontroller. In my microcontroller of choice, (STM32) I have available a fast ADC and know the carrier frequency. Can someone point to a simple example in c or Python code that shows how to do this using multiplication and shifting functions only? It is impossible to implement certain complex scipy functions in a microcontroller. Also, since I know the carrier frequency, is it ok to shift the sampled signal by n bins to get a 90degree phase shift or is this dangerous if there are slight deviations between the crystals of the transmitting and receiving ends?

Where does it use Scipy?  The article mentions using the CMSIS library -- that's not Scipy, that's ARM's math library.  Since it's from ARM, it's available for the STM32 as well.

This specific example doesn't use Scipy but I'm actually after an example that is not computationally intensive, i.e. without floating point or trig calculations.
